# How to set conditionally suppress of page header of a crystal report subreport based on record number?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, subreport

I am using crystal report in vb.net.  I have a mainreport and a subreport.  What I want to do is to suppress the page header of the subreport if the recordnumber of the mainreport is greater than one.  So basically, what will happen is the subreport's page header will only show once which should be the first record in the mainreport.  I tried using conditional suppress using shared variables but I was not able to make it work.  Must be doing something wrong.

Here is what I created in the mainreport formula field with formula name

```
Record_num:
Shared numbervar x;
x := recordnumber;
```

And here is what I created in the subreport formula field with formula name

```
record_num:
Shared numbervar x;
```

And then I created a conditional suppress for the subreport's page header:

```
{@record_num} > 1
```

When I run the program, it does not work, the page header still shows in all the records of mainreport instead of only the first one.

Comment: finally after experimenting, got it to work, need to put whileprintingrecords; before the declaration.  And the formula field created (shared variables) need to be drag in the report itself for it to have value.   Thanks.

Comment: An alternative and cleaner option in my opinion would be to pass the recordnumber as a parameter using the the subreport links.

Comment: I already have a parameter field that link the main report to the subreport.  I think adding more than one paramater field is not possible.